# How to print a dictionary line by line in Python?

Tags: python, printing, dictionary

This is the dictionary

```
cars = {'A':{'speed':70,
        'color':2},
        'B':{'speed':60,
        'color':3}}
```

Using this `for loop`

```
for keys,values in cars.items():
    print(keys)
    print(values)
```

It prints the following:

```
B
{'color': 3, 'speed': 60}
A
{'color': 2, 'speed': 70}
```

But I want the program to print it like this:

```
B
color : 3
speed : 60
A
color : 2
speed : 70
```

I just started learning dictionaries so I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

```
for x in cars:
    print (x)
    for y in cars[x]:
        print (y,':',cars[x][y])
```

output:

```
A
color : 2
speed : 70
B
color : 3
speed : 60
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I thought it would be worth mentioning that this doesn't work if cars[x] is integers. It isn't what the OP was requesting, so I'm just saying it for anybody that stumbles upon this assuming it's a blanket solution.

Comment: @DarrelHolt do you know how to make it work with integers? Because that's the problem I'm currently facing

Comment: @theprowler The closest I can get to recreating the problem is if `cars = {1:4,
        2:5}` then `cars[x]` is an integer mapped to the key `x` rather than a set mapped to the key `x`. In this case, you don't need to use the `for y in cars[x]:` line because there's only one value you're retrieving, unless you're using something like a list or set of integers then it should work. Sorry, it's been a few months so I can't completely remember how I came to the conclusion of my previous comment. You could send me your code and I can see if I'm any help.

Comment: Hmm. I think my problem is even worse than that. Basically I've parsed out some data from an HTML table, and I happened to store it in a dictionary, and now I'm trying to take that dictionary data and put it into a DataFrame before I export it all to an Oracle table....it's pretty in depth I know, but the step that is holding me up right now is putting the data into a DataFrame....my dictionary for some reason has one key and all the data is in values, so it's difficult trying to put it neatly into rows and columns..

Answer (score 172):

You could use the `json` module for this. The `dumps` function in this module converts a JSON object into a properly formatted string which you can then print.

```
import json

cars = {'A':{'speed':70, 'color':2},
        'B':{'speed':60, 'color':3}}

print(json.dumps(cars, indent = 4))
```

The output looks like

```
{
    "A": {
        "color": 2,
        "speed": 70
    },
    "B": {
        "color": 3,
        "speed": 60
    }
}
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage) also specifies a bunch of useful options for this method.

Comment: true, the contents of the dict must be serializable into json, however, the output provided here is far cleaner (e.g., human readable) than output produced by the pprint.PrettyPrinter. specifically in the area of consistent indentation and discarding of string prefixes such as u'foo'.

Comment: I do `print(json.dumps(cars, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))` because otherwise non-ASCII characters are unreadable.

Answer (score 87):

A more generalized solution that handles arbitrarily-deeply nested dicts and lists would be:

```
def dumpclean(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if hasattr(v, '__iter__'):
                print k
                dumpclean(v)
            else:
                print '%s : %s' % (k, v)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for v in obj:
            if hasattr(v, '__iter__'):
                dumpclean(v)
            else:
                print v
    else:
        print obj
```

This produces the output:

```
A
color : 2
speed : 70
B
color : 3
speed : 60
```

I ran into a similar need and developed a more robust function as an exercise for myself.  I'm including it here in case it can be of value to another.  In running nosetest, I also found it helpful to be able to specify the output stream in the call so that sys.stderr could be used instead.

```
import sys

def dump(obj, nested_level=0, output=sys.stdout):
    spacing = '   '
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        print >> output, '%s{' % ((nested_level) * spacing)
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if hasattr(v, '__iter__'):
                print >> output, '%s%s:' % ((nested_level + 1) * spacing, k)
                dump(v, nested_level + 1, output)
            else:
                print >> output, '%s%s: %s' % ((nested_level + 1) * spacing, k, v)
        print >> output, '%s}' % (nested_level * spacing)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        print >> output, '%s[' % ((nested_level) * spacing)
        for v in obj:
            if hasattr(v, '__iter__'):
                dump(v, nested_level + 1, output)
            else:
                print >> output, '%s%s' % ((nested_level + 1) * spacing, v)
        print >> output, '%s]' % ((nested_level) * spacing)
    else:
        print >> output, '%s%s' % (nested_level * spacing, obj)
```

Using this function, the OP's output looks like this:

```
{
   A:
   {
      color: 2
      speed: 70
   }
   B:
   {
      color: 3
      speed: 60
   }
}
```

which I personally found to be more useful and descriptive.

Given the slightly less-trivial example of:

```
{"test": [{1:3}], "test2":[(1,2),(3,4)],"test3": {(1,2):['abc', 'def', 'ghi'],(4,5):'def'}}
```

The OP's requested solution yields this:

```
test
1 : 3
test3
(1, 2)
abc
def
ghi
(4, 5) : def
test2
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
```

whereas the 'enhanced' version yields this:

```
{
   test:
   [
      {
         1: 3
      }
   ]
   test3:
   {
      (1, 2):
      [
         abc
         def
         ghi
      ]
      (4, 5): def
   }
   test2:
   [
      (1, 2)
      (3, 4)
   ]
}
```

I hope this provides some value to the next person looking for this type of functionality.

Comment: And if the format is not overly strict, one could also use 'print json.dumps(obj, indent=3)'.  That gives a reasonable representation of most structures, though it does choke (in my environment) on my less-trivial example due to the use of a tuple as a key...

Comment: Why not just use [`pprint.pprint()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) here then?

Comment: almost made a JSON creator, no?

Answer (score 58):

[`pprint.pprint()`](https://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) is a good tool for this job:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> cars = {'A':{'speed':70,
...         'color':2},
...         'B':{'speed':60,
...         'color':3}}
>>> pprint.pprint(cars, width=1)
{'A': {'color': 2,
       'speed': 70},
 'B': {'color': 3,
       'speed': 60}}
```

Comment: This seem to be the simplest and best solution by far, as it can also handle *sets, tuples* and *lists* when nested in the *dict*.

Comment: I think it is better to use `pprint` without `width` option, otherwise it also breaks the phrases that have spaces between each word.

Answer (score 33):

You have a nested structure, so you need to format the nested dictionary too:

```
for key, car in cars.items():
    print(key)
    for attribute, value in car.items():
        print('{} : {}'.format(attribute, value))
```

This prints:

```
A
color : 2
speed : 70
B
color : 3
speed : 60
```

Answer (score 18):

I prefer the clean formatting of `yaml`:

```
import yaml
print(yaml.dump(cars))
```

output:

```
A:
  color: 2
  speed: 70
B:
  color: 3
  speed: 60
```

Comment: You have to `pip install PyYAML` first.

Comment: unlike `pprint` example above, this seem to break when there are lists nested within dicts.

Comment: Very nice and compact solution. Just had to add the `print` statement.

Answer (score 8):

```
for car,info in cars.items():
    print(car)
    for key,value in info.items():
        print(key, ":", value)
```

Answer (score 5):

This will work if you know the tree only has two levels:

```
for k1 in cars:
    print(k1)
    d = cars[k1]
    for k2 in d
        print(k2, ':', d[k2])
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the following one-liner:

```
print('\n'.join("%s\n%s" % (key1,('\n'.join("%s : %r" % (key2,val2) for (key2,val2) in val1.items()))) for (key1,val1) in cars.items()))
```

Output:

```
A
speed : 70
color : 2
B
speed : 60
color : 3
```

Comment: Nice one, but I tried to convert it to use this with `sys.modules`, but I failed. Wanna have a go at it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the problem. I think it's similar in approach, but a little simpler than some of the other answers. It also allows for an arbitrary  number of sub-dictionaries and seems to work for any datatype (I even tested it on a dictionary which had functions as values):

```
def pprint(web, level):
    for k,v in web.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            print('\t'*level, f'{k}: ')
            level += 1
            pprint(v, level)
            level -= 1
        else:
            print('\t'*level, k, ": ", v)
```

Comment: I don't see how this is simpler than other answers. Certainly not for readability. Also would be great to see some example output from this.

Answer (score 0):

Made one liner. Outputs exactly what you want.

```
cars = {'A':{'speed':70,
        'color':2},
        'B':{'speed':60,
        'color':3}}
print('\n'.join(f'{k}\n'+'\n'.join(f'{k2} : {v}' for k2,v in reversed(cars[k].items())) for k in reversed(cars)))
```

Also, tried run with `timeit` all solutions. And mine was always slowest.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a little bit to @MrWonderful 's answer and also converted it from Python2 to Python3.

The new version now has 2 big features.

1. Separators
2. Prefixes

```
    def print_pretty(
            obj,
            nested_level=0,
            output=sys.stdout,
            prefixes_at = ["all"],
            prefixes = ["|>"],
            spacing_amount = 4,
            separators_at_every = [0, 1, 2],
            separators = ["|______________\n|", "    |----------", "        |"]
    ):
    
    
        spacing = ''
        for i in range(0, spacing_amount):
            spacing += ' '
    
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            for k, v in list(obj.items()):
                sep_index = -1
                try:
                    sep_index = separators_at_every.index(nested_level)
                except ValueError as e:
                    pass  # not in list
                if sep_index != -1:
                    print(separators[sep_index])
    
                if hasattr(v, '__iter__') and type(v) != str:
                    text = '%s' % (nested_level * spacing)
                    if len(prefixes) > 0:
                        prefix_index = -1
                        try:
                            prefix_index = prefixes_at.index(nested_level)
                        except:
                            pass
                        if prefix_index != -1 or prefixes_at[0] == "all":
                            text += prefixes[prefix_index]
                    text += '%s:' % k
                    print(text, file=output)
    
                    print_pretty(v, nested_level + 1, output)
                else:
                    text = '%s' % (nested_level * spacing)
    
                    if len(prefixes) > 0:
                        prefix_index = -1
                        try:
                            prefix_index = prefixes_at.index(nested_level)
                        except:
                            pass
                        if prefix_index != -1 or prefixes_at[0] == "all":
                            text += prefixes[prefix_index]
                    text += '%s: %s' % (k, v)
                    print(text, file=output)
    
        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            for v in obj:
                if hasattr(v, '__iter__'):
                    print_pretty(v, nested_level + 1, output)
                else:
                    text = '%s' % (nested_level + 1 * spacing)
    
                    if len(prefixes) > 0:
                        prefix_index = -1
                        try:
                            prefix_index = prefixes_at.index(nested_level)
                        except:
                            pass
                        if prefix_index != -1 or prefixes_at[0] == "all":
                            text += prefixes[prefix_index]
                    text += '%s' % v
                    print(text, file=output)
        else:
            if nested_level > 0:
                nested_level -= 1
            print('%s  > %s' % (nested_level * spacing, obj), file=output)
```

[Example Data (JSON)'s image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfX2A.png)

[Example Console Output's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akS3R.png)

Answer (score 0):

Also iterating your construction twice works

```
for keys,values in cars.items():
    print(keys)
    for key2,value2 in values.items():
        print(key2,":",value2)
```

This is so, because you have a dictionary which values are dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

```
###newbie exact answer desired (Python v3):
###=================================
"""
cars = {'A':{'speed':70,
        'color':2},
        'B':{'speed':60,
        'color':3}}
"""

for keys, values in  reversed(sorted(cars.items())):
    print(keys)
    for keys,values in sorted(values.items()):
        print(keys," : ", values)

"""
Output:
B
color  :  3
speed  :  60
A
color  :  2
speed  :  70

##[Finished in 0.073s]
"""
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# Declare and Initialize Map
map = {}

map ["New"] = 1
map ["to"] = 1
map ["Python"] = 5
map ["or"] = 2

# Print Statement
for i in map:
  print ("", i, ":", map[i])

#  New : 1
#  to : 1
#  Python : 5
#  or : 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this.

```
cars = {'A':{'speed':70,
        'color':2},
        'B':{'speed':60,
        'color':3}}

print(str(cars).replace(",", ",\n"))
```

output:

```
{'A': {'speed': 70,
 'color': 2},
 'B': {'speed': 60,
 'color': 3}}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think list comprehension is the cleanest way to do this:

```py
mydict = {a:1, b:2, c:3}

[(print("key:", key, end='\t'), print('value:', value)) for key, value in mydict.items()]
```

Answer (score -2):

Modifying MrWonderful code

```
import sys

def print_dictionary(obj, ident):
    if type(obj) == dict:
        for k, v in obj.items():
            sys.stdout.write(ident)
            if hasattr(v, '__iter__'):
                print k
                print_dictionary(v, ident + '  ')
            else:
                print '%s : %s' % (k, v)
    elif type(obj) == list:
        for v in obj:
            sys.stdout.write(ident)
            if hasattr(v, '__iter__'):
                print_dictionary(v, ident + '  ')
            else:
                print v
    else:
        print obj
```

Comment: What did you modify? What's the output?