# Print dictionary of list values

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary values, as given below:

```
{'ID 2': [{'game': 586, 'start': 1436882375, 'process': 13140}, {'game': 585, 'start': 1436882375, 'process': 13116}], 'ID 1': [{'game': 582, 'start': 1436882375, 'process': 13094}, {'game': 583, 'start': 1436882375, 'process': 12934}, {'game': 584, 'start': 1436882375, 'process': 12805}]}
```

It is barely readable. I want to format it this way:

```
'ID 2' : {'game': 586, 'start': 1436882375, 'process': 13140},
'ID 2' : {'game': 585, 'start': 1436882375, 'process': 13116},
'ID 1' : {'game': 582, 'start': 1436882375, 'process': 13094},
'ID 1' : {'game': 582, 'start': 1436882375, 'process': 13094},
```

My code for printing is given below:

```
 for key in queue_dict.items():
        for values in key.values():
            print(key+" : "+values)
```

The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'values'
```

I cannot understand how to access each dictionary in the list value of each key. I searched a lot, but couldn't really find an answer. Can someone help?

Comment: There are some good ways in the answers : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785719/how-to-print-a-dictionary-line-by-line-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785719/how-to-print-a-dictionary-line-by-line-in-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=items#dict.items) returns a tuple of the key value pairs.

> Return a new view of the dictionary’s items ((key, value) pairs)

You will have to do this instead.

```
for key,values in queue_dict.items():
     for v in values:
          print(key," : ",v)
```

Also you can not concatenate an `str` object and a `dict` object using `+`. You will get a `TypeError`. So you will have to cast it to a `str`. Instead you can use format as in `print("{} : {}".format(key,v))`

Comment: Glad to be of help to you. All the best.