# How to print Dictionary output into new line while looking for duplicate lines

Tags: python-3.x

I have Just opted the below code which is working fine to determine the duplicate line and line numbers and this works fine.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def find_dupl(log):
    output = defaultdict(list)
    with open(log) as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            line = line.strip()
            output[line].append(i)
        print({k: v for k, v in output.items() if len(v) > 1})
find_dupl('rhel65')
```

The result output is as follows, i every host name or item to be printed into new line.

```
{'hostlab01': [0, 1], 'hostlab02': [34, 35, 36]}
```

Desired would be :

> ```
> hostlab01: [0, 1] 
> hostlab02: [34, 35, 36]
> ```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785719/how-to-print-a-dictionary-line-by-line-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change one line in your function:

```
print(*['{}: {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in output.items() if len(v) > 1], sep='\n')
```

Comment: @pygo Asterisk `*` here means unpacking of the list and passing its content to the function print as separate variables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Change the output of your function by removing the print statement and defining instead a generator:

```
def find_dupl(log):
    output = defaultdict(list)
    with open(log) as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            line = line.strip()
            output[line].append(i)
   result = {k: v for k, v in output.items() if len(v) > 1}
   for k, v in result.items():
       yield k, v

for key, value in find_dupl('rhel65'):
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

That should give you the expected result if I am right.

Answer (score 1):

change your print line to:

```
print("\n".join("{}\t{}".format(k, v) for k, v in output.items() if len(v) > 1))
```