# How to print only print all the values of a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my hash/dictionary

```
word_hash = {
    '1': 'Awkward',
    '2': 'Bagpipes',
    '3': 'Banjo',
    '4': 'Bungler',
    '5': 'Croquet',
    '6': 'Crypt',
    '7': 'Dwarves',
    '8': 'Fervid',
    '9': 'Fishhook',
    '10': 'Fjord',
    '11': 'Gazebo',
    '12': 'Gypsy',
    '13': 'Haiku',
    '14': 'Haphazard',
    '15': 'Hyphen',
    '16': 'Ivory',
    '17': 'Jiffy',
    '18': 'Jinx',
    '19': 'Jukebox',
    '20': 'Kayak',
    '21': 'Kiosk',
    '22': 'Klutz',
    '23': 'Memento',
    '24': 'Mystify',
    '25': 'Numbskull',
    '26': 'Ostracize',
    '27': 'Oxygen',
    '28': 'Pajama',
    '29': 'Phlegm',
    '30': 'Pixel',
    '31': 'Polka',
    '32': 'Quad',
    '33': 'Quip',
    '34': 'Rhythmic',
    '35': 'Rogue',
    '36': 'Sphinx',
    '37': 'Squawk',
    '38': 'Swivel',
    '39': 'Toady',
    '40': 'Twelfth',
    '41': 'Unzip',
    '43': 'Waxy',
    '44': 'Wildebeest',
    '45': 'Yacht',
    '46': 'Zealous',
    '47': 'Zigzag',
    '48': 'Zippy',
    '49': 'Zombie',
}
```

I want to make a an array of only the values and print it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a dictionary line by line in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785719/how-to-print-a-dictionary-line-by-line-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the values of the dict in random order, you can use `random.shuffle`:

```
from random import shuffle
values = list(word_hash.values())
shuffle(values)
print(values)
```

Comment: afaik he wants randomness :/

Comment: @IshaniChakravorty I've updated my answer with how you can randomize the values of the dict then.

Answer (score 3):

Python's dict has method `values()` that returns it. So you want to `print(word_hash.values())`

Comment: What do you mean by randomize? You want to pick n random values?

Comment: import random module and then `random.sample(word_hash.values(), 15)` or any your number.

Comment: what does 15 do?

Comment: It's a number of random elements to pick.