# How to print information from dictionary in format? error message:'dict' object has no attribute 'format'

Tags: python, python-3.x

trying to get the output:

```
Kayleigh:
True 100
True 80
True 67
True 100
True 89
```

from the dictionary I made:

```
kayleigh = {'name':'Kayleigh',
            'grades':[100,80,67,100,89],
            'attendance':['True','True','True','True','True']}
```

since the grades and attendance both have 5 items so I try to match them, but there's this error message saying that the format is not built in dictionary.

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 print ("Kayleigh:",{},{}.format(kayleigh.get('attendance'),kayleigh.get('grades')))

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: Where is your faulty code? We can not fix what we do not see ...

Comment: The error is self-explainatory: `.format()` is not defined on `dict` - it is a defined in `str.format()` - there are a bazillion examples around showing how to print a dictionary - which ones did you research and what did you use?

Comment: See f.e. for complex formatting: [how-to-pretty-print-nested-dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229419/how-to-pretty-print-nested-dictionaries) or for much simpler needs: [how-to-print-a-dictionary-line-by-line-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785719/how-to-print-a-dictionary-line-by-line-in-python)

Comment: Please note that you have some time remaining before this post is being closed as unclear. Kindly post your code and explain where in the code you are stuck to avoid it.

Comment: `@WY G`, please show what you tried (code), it would be better to answer you before digging the hill. Are you using `format()` method defined on string.

Comment: Thank you. I just edited my post. I will keep in mind next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to do your job:

```
    kayleigh = {'name':'Kayleigh',
            'grades':[100,80,67,100,89],
            'attendance':['True','True','True','True','True']}

print(kayleigh['name'],':')
for i in range (len (kayleigh['attendance'])):
    print(kayleigh['attendance'][i],kayleigh['grades'][i])
```

Comment: Thank you! its really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this (or for better view, you can check [this notebook on Github](https://github.com/hygull/pyrandocs/blob/master/python3/stackoverflow/dict_func.ipynb).

```
# Defining a function which will do the task
def print_message(d):
    print(d["name"] + ':')

    for attendance, grade in zip(d["attendance"], d["grades"]):
        print(attendance, grade)

# Initialization
kayleigh = {'name':'Kayleigh',
            'grades':[100,80,67,100,89],
            'attendance':['True','True','True','True','True']}

# Making a call to te function by passing an appropriate dictionary 
print_message(kayleigh)
```

> Output

```
Kayleigh:
True 100
True 80
True 67
True 100
True 89
```

If you want to try it from the terminal then here is how will you do.

```
>>> def print_message(d):
...     print(d["name"] + ':')
...     for attendance, grade in zip(d["attendance"], d["grades"]):
...         print(attendance, grade)
... 
>>> kayleigh = {'name':'Kayleigh',
...             'grades':[100,80,67,100,89],
...             'attendance':['True','True','True','True','True']}
>>> print_message(kayleigh)
Kayleigh:
True 100
True 80
True 67
True 100
True 89
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am not very familiar with the zip() function. is it only applied to dictionary?

Comment: Yes, you are welcome `@WY G`. `zip()` is basically to iterate over 2 or more lists/tuples simultaneously. Have a look at https://www.journaldev.com/15891/python-zip-function for more details.