# This prints out the dictionary but how can I have it line by line

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random

def main():

    Sobeys = {'broccoli': 1.27, 'muffins': 5.0, 'donuts': 1.85,
          'yogurt': 2.41, 'bagels': 4.91, 'bread': 4.48,
          'cupcakes': 3.54}

    print("Sobeys prices:")
    display(Sobeys)

def display(grocery_dict):
    print (grocery_dict)
    return

main()
```

How can I have this print everything in the dictionary line by line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a dictionary line by line in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785719/how-to-print-a-dictionary-line-by-line-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
Sobeys = {'broccoli': 1.27, 'muffins': 5.0, 'donuts': 1.85,
'yogurt': 2.41, 'bagels': 4.91, 'bread': 4.48, 'cupcakes': 3.54}

for item in Sobeys:
    print(item+" costs $"+str(Sobeys[item]))
```

This will iterate over the dictionary, printing the name of each item and how much it costs.  You can customize it by changing the `print` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `items()` method and for loop to iterate over the key, value pairs in a dictionary.

```
Sobeys = {'broccoli': 1.27, 'muffins': 5.0, 'donuts': 1.85,
          'yogurt': 2.41, 'bagels': 4.91, 'bread': 4.48,
          'cupcakes': 3.54}

for k,v in Sobeys.items():
    print(f"'{k}' \t: {v}")
```