# How to print a sorted dictionary without curly braces and single quote (python)

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

So, I need to print the sales of my hotel management system both in ascending and descending order. I found these codes down below which solved my problem (yes, I'm a total beginner).

```
    def ascend(self, dict):
        print({k: v for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])})

    def descend(self, dict):
        print({k: v for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)})
```

It does print out the sales but the output has a single quote around the key, curly braces, and only in one line which is the total opposite of my desired output. How do I sort in ascending and descending while printing each in a new line without the curly braces and the single quote?

Big thanks to anyone who could help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a dictionary line by line in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785719/how-to-print-a-dictionary-line-by-line-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it

```
def ascend(dict):
   sorted_dict = {k: v for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
   for key, value in sorted_dict.items():
      print(key, ',', value)

def descend(self, dict):
   sorted_dict = {k: v for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
   for key, value in sorted_dict.items():
      print(key, ',', value)
```

What I did here is I saved the sorted dictionary in a variable and then iterated over that dictionary to print its content in the desired format.